# org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLHNUM: Problem unpacking field 44 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 3634 too long. Max: 25) unpacking field=44, consumed=87

Tags: java, spring, iso8583, jpos

I have been trying send a flag in `ISO 8583 spec` - in field 40 which will yield 44 field in response.

Seeing the below error...

```
all other field gets unpacked just fine expect this filed 44.
<log realm="client-logger/168.244.126.8:10096" at="2023-06-27T06:38:56.573210" lifespan="70ms">
  <receive>
    <iso-exception>
       org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLHNUM: Problem unpacking field 44 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 3634 too long. Max: 25) unpacking field=44, consumed=87
      org.jpos.iso.ISOException: org.jpos.iso.IFB_LLLHNUM: Problem unpacking field 44 (org.jpos.iso.ISOException: Field length 3634 too long. Max: 25) unpacking field=44, consumed=87
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOBasePackager.unpack(ISOBasePackager.java:340)
        at org.jpos.iso.ISOMsg.unpack(ISOMsg.java:468)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.unpack(BaseChannel.java:976)
        at org.jpos.iso.BaseChannel.receive(BaseChannel.java:746)
```

ISOPACKAGER:

```
/*Field 44 */  new IFB_LLLHNUM(25, "EOV Date", true),  //has to be Ascii
```

I tried truncating the field 44 to size 25.

Saw this on logs: seems like it's returning some ASCII special characters while receiving the msg we are seeing this error, whereas the request is reaching them just fine.

```
0000  03 10 78 B8 00 01 86 D0  B0 00 13 06 00 64 91 73  ..x..........d.s
0010  14 99 80 09 25 92 00 00  00 00 00 00 50 00 00 00  ....%.......P...
0020  00 00 50 00 61 00 00 00  75 82 44 13 29 36 06 18  ..P.a...u.D.)6..
0030  05 06 76 24 05 06 82 50  30 30 35 30 30 30 30 31  ..v$...P00500001
0040  30 30 30 37 35 38 32 34  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 39  0007582400000009
0050  39 38 30 30 30 30 30 0E  32 30 32 33 30 39 32 35  9800000.20230925
0060  54 31 33 32 30 5A 08 40  08 40 30 30 30 30 37 37  T1320Z.@.@000077
0070  30 39                                             09
```

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix my issue by changing field 44 IFB_LLLHNUM --> IFB_LLHCHAR

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).